# How to load HTML templates from a module in Golang?

Tags: go, go-templates, go-modules

I am working on my own project where I have some separate repositories and each repository will have its own template folder and handlers.

I want to combine and load templates in the main repository where I'm importing all the modules. But I'm not able to find a way to load those templates. Is there any way I can copy those templates into the main repository's templates folder from Git? So, that I can run the template engine.

thanks

Comment: I don't want to embed templates and I think it will also not work. Will it?

Comment: Why don’t you want to embed the templates?  What is the “template engine”?

Comment: Hi @CharlieTumahai 

I'm using gofiber v2 with HTML template v2 provided by gofiber. I don't want to embed it because it will make the binary file larger in size.

Is that okay or should I embed?

Comment: I also tried embedding though, but It didn't work.

Comment: Embedding the templates in the executable takes the same amount of disk space as distributing the templates as separate files.   See https://github.com/gofiber/template/tree/master/html#example-with-embedfs for information on how to use embedded templates with fiber.